# ag-grid: Disable cells based on content in other cells on the same row

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm looking for help about a feature I will implement using ag-grid. 
[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ojxDBOeUoUlj8ROcaksO?p=preview) is a plunker.

I have a table with X items and 3 columns. In the the first column, I have some readonly text and in the second and third columns I have custom `cellEditor` (on click a dropdown menu is displayed).

Target: I want the cells in the third column to be disabled by default (on click, the dropdown is not displayed) and the dropdown is displayed (in a cell in the third column) only if the cell on the second column on the same row has value (an item is selected from the dropdown).

```
enter code here (must have code in order to put plunker links :/)
```

Example: On row one: column 1 has value (by default) and the user select an item from the dropdown on column 2. Then and only then he is able to select an item from the dropdown in the third column. The user is not able to select an item from the third column on other rows since their column two is empty.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can handle `editable` mode dynamically

```
headerName: 'C',
field: 'c',
cellEditor: 'searchEditor',
editable: (params:IsColumnFuncParams)=>{ return params.data.b },
cellEditorParams: {
    values: this.c
}
```

> *Set to true if this col is editable, otherwise false. Can also be a function to have different rows editable.*

```
editable?: boolean | IsColumnFunc;
```

> `ag-grid-community\src\ts\entities\colDef.ts`

```
export interface IsColumnFuncParams {
    node: RowNode;
    data: any;
    column: Column;
    colDef: ColDef;
    context: any;
    api: GridApi;
    columnApi: ColumnApi;
}
```

**Update: [`singleClickEdit`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-properties/#reference-editing-singleClickEdit)**

> Set to `true` to enable `Single Click Editing` for cells, to start editing with a single click. See [`Single Click Editing`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/cell-editing/#single-click-editing).
> `Default: false`

Comment: Vote up, as this does in fact resolve the issue in question. One additional note though worth mentioning is that "editable" is a callback being hit any time the cell is being edited.  At the start I thought this would only happen once on columns setup, however, I am happy to say this is not the case. Good solution!

Comment: suppressClickEdit

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on **AlexRebula**'s excellent tip, here's what you can do, with `editable`:

```
header: 'username',
editable: (params:IsColumnFuncParams)=> { return this.canCellBeEdited(params) },
cellRenderer: 'searchEditor',

. . . 

    canCellBeEdited(params) {
        //  Don't let the user edit the "First Name" cell, if the current value is "mike".
        if (params.colDef.field == 'firstName' && params.data[params.colDef.field] == 'mike') {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```